# How can I have the search results page stay in place be remembered whilst navigating back and fourth to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the 'back' button or the 'refresh/reload' button in the browser my search/filtered results disappear even though the 'input box' stays OK and remembers the typed keyword. How can I have the results page stay with the keyword whilst navigating back and fourth to the page, or refreshing/reloading?

```js
 var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;
    $(document).ready(function init() {
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

    table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
    rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

    markInstance = new Mark(table);
    input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
    });    


    function ContactsearchFX() {
      resetContent();
      markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
    }



    function resetContent() {
        $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
        //Remove this line to have a log of searches

        //noMatches.textContent = '';
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        $(row).removeClass('show'); 
      });
    }

    function highlightMatches() {
      markInstance.mark(input.value, {
        each: showRow,
        noMatch: onNoMatches,
        exclude: ['.nonsearch']
      })
    }



    function showRow(element) {
    //alert(element);
      $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');                $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
            //Parents incase of several nestings
    }



    function onNoMatches(text) {
      $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +     text +                 '"</p>'); 
    }
    
    
    
    /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */
    
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
    /* on form submit find the trigger */
    if( $(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0 ){
        /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    } 
    });    
    
        /* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */    



    // Save data to sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

    // Get saved data from sessionStorage
    let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

```css
.input-wrap  {
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }

    #myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
      display: block;
    }



    #noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
      display: none;
    }


    .style1 tr {
      display: none;
    }


    .style1 .show {
      display: table-row;
    }



    #myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
    background: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    }
    mark {
    background: initial;
    }    .style1  {
    text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
    /mark.min.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
    <div class="input-wrap">
    <label>
    Search 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required
       placeholder="Search Titles" />
    </label>
    </div>

    <div class="hintsWrap">
    <p id="noMatches"></p>
    <p class="hints">
    Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
    </p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date1</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <br />
    <br />
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Type</th>
                    <td>type3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Title</th>
                    <td>title3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Description</th>
                    <td>description3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="style1">Date</th>
                    <td>date3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Add the search term into the url `mysite.com/?search=words`, then on page load check the url for a search term and load that search page.

Comment: Can use ```localStorage``` too.

Comment: Please do expand...